# typo3 and typo3cms command line tools: list inactive extensions

Tags: typo3, command-line-tool

I have a TYPO3 CMS v10 system running and have a question about the `typo3` and `typo3cms` command line tools.

Maybe it is just me but I cannot figure out a way to list all the *inactive* ("deactivated") extensions that are installed in the system, *via the command line*.

When I run `typo3 extension:list`

I get this output

```
All installed (= active) extensions
===================================

+--------------------------------+------------+----------+--------+
| Extension Key                  | Version    | Type     | Status |
+--------------------------------+------------+----------+--------+
| core                           | 10.4.22    | System   | active |
| scheduler                      | 10.4.22    | System   | active |
| extbase                        | 10.4.22    | System   | active |
...many more
```

But this listing does not contain any inactive extensions. The rightmost column always has the value "active". (It is useless)

There is an alternative, better, command-line tool, `typo3cms`, and the subcommand

`typo3cms extension:list`

however, gives this output:

```
 -------------------------- ----------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Extension key              Version     Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 -------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  core                       10.4.22     The core library of TYPO3.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  scheduler                  10.4.22     The TYPO3 Scheduler let's you register tasks to happen at a specific time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  extbase                    10.4.22     A framework to build extensions for TYPO3 CMS. 
...many more
```

This output lists *all* extensions, active and deactivated, but it does not contain a `Status` column (unlike the first listing).

Again: how can I get a listing of only the *inactive* extensions, with the command line?

I am familiar with the standard unix command line tools, so any help with additional tools (e.g. `grep`, `jq`) is fine with me.

(I know can get this information this via the graphical backend, extension manager panel)

Comment: Do you have inactive extensions? When you use composer and generate the packagestates file with typo3_console, you never have inactive extensions. There is no need for inactive extensions, are they?

Comment: I have my own extensions under development, and I go through an activate-deactivate-activate cycle for testing the installation process. Sometimes the renewed installation fails and the extension remains deactivated.  There are other scenarios where I prefer to deactivate the extension *temporarily* on purpose. Besides there are TER extension that require some extra work, and until this is not done I prefer to leave the extension in a deactivated state. (this gets too long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typo3 extension:list` has an option to list all available extensions, including deactivated ones. So `typo3 extension:list -a` will give you a complete list, instead of just the active ones.

Comment: Thanks! Very simple. It's weird, that the `-a` option does not show up in the output of  `typo3 help list`. I probably only tried that comand. But now I see that `-a` *does* show up in `typo3 help extension:list`

Answer (score 5):

I guess the answer you are looking for is not available but nevertheless I want to give some background:

Using the typo3 console and commands like `typo3cms extension:setupactive` which usually hook into the composer install/update commands will activate all extensions which are provided by composer (or available in typo3conf/ext).

With TYPO3 11 and using composer, there is no inactive extension available anymore and there is no way to disable the extension in the extension manager anymore. See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.4/Feature-94996-ConsiderAllComposerInstalledExtensionsAsActive.html

Therefore I suggest to adopt your workflows already in 10 as you need to get used to it in 11 anyways.